# Extending PHP classes with different shared methods and properties

Tags: php, class, oop

I have the following three objects which includes the following methods and properties:

```
$obj1
 - $prop1
 - $prop2
 - $prop3
 - $prop4
 - method1()
 - method2()
 - method3()
 - method4()

$obj2
 - $prop2
 - $prop3
 - $prop4
 - $prop5
 - method2()
 - method3()
 - method4()
 - method5()

$obj3
 - $prop1
 - $prop3
 - $prop4
 - $prop5
 - method1()
 - method3()
 - method4()
 - method5()
```

All properties and methods of a given name utilize identical script to create them.

One possible script to create these objects is as follows:

```
class class1 { 
  var $prop1=123, $prop2=array(), $prop3, $prop4;
  public method method1($x) {echo('hello '.$x;}
  public method method2($x) {echo('goodby '.$x;}
  public method method3($x) {echo('hey '.$x;}
  public method method4($x) {echo('seeya '.$x;}
}

class class2 { 
  var $prop2=array(), $prop3, $prop4, $prop5=555,;
  public method method2($x) {echo('goodby '.$x;}
  public method method3($x) {echo('hey '.$x;}
  public method method4($x) {echo('seeya '.$x;}
  public method method5($x) {echo('latter '.$x;}
}

class class3 { 
  var $prop1=123,  $prop3, $prop4, $prop5=555,;
  public method method1($x) {echo('hello '.$x;}
  public method method3($x) {echo('hey '.$x;}
  public method method4($x) {echo('seeya '.$x;}
  public method method5($x) {echo('latter '.$x;}
}
```

How can I create these three objects without duplicating the script used to create the properties and methods?

Comment: What are you asking?  We need more info than this.  What do you mean by "utilize identical script" and "without duplicating the script"?  How *exactly* are you creating these and what *exactly* are you trying to do instead?

Comment: Sounds like a good excuse to read about [Traits](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)

Comment: @MarkBaker The same thought came into my head when I read the title, but when I read the question it looks more like an xy problem

Comment: @RocketHazmat  I wish to create a class with with script to create each method.  If there were only two needed objects, I could just locate the shared methods in some `parentClass`, and extend this class to create each, but I don't know how to do so when needing three objects where some of them are only used in each individual object.

Comment: Of course, if you were using the yet-to-be-released PHP 7, you have the option of Anonymous Classes

Comment: Can you show us this "script" that's creating the classes?

Comment: Could you use the 'property and method' creation scripts inside the individual `factories' that create these objects? It would allow re-use of the 'generation' code? How complex is the 'generation code'? I am not sure that 'inheritance' is the way to go when creating your objects as they are very different from each other.

Comment: @RocketHazmat  Please see added script to my original post.

Comment: So, not all of your classes use *all* of the same methods?

Comment: @RocketHazmat  Correct.  That is the issue.

Comment: If you wanted to use them in `common scenarios` then I would suggest using `interfaces` for the individual `methods` such as `method1` etc. That way, you can pass them about for `common processing` for the individual methods, even though they are very different objects but with common processing requirements?

Comment: @MarkBaker  Just read up on Traits.  Never heard of them before.  Looks like a good solution.  Thanks

Comment: @RyanVincent  I thought that `interfaces` were just used to enforce that a given class defines various methods.  How do you recommend using `interfaces` to meet my stated requirements?  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested and not positive it will work.  Also, concerned it will be difficult to maintain.

```
trait trait_1{
  var $prop1=123;
  public method method1($x) {echo('hello '.$x;}
}
trait trait_2{
  $prop2=array();
  public method method2($x) {echo('goodby '.$x;}
}
trait trait_5{
   $prop5=555;
  public method method5($x) {echo('latter '.$x;}
}

trait trait_3_4{
  var $prop3, $prop4;
  public method method3($x) {echo('hey '.$x;}
  public method method4($x) {echo('seeya '.$x;}
}

class class1 { 
  use trait_1, trait_2,  trait_3_4;
}
class class2 { 
  use trait_2,  trait_3_4, trait_5;
}
class class3 { 
  use trait_1,  trait_3_4, trait_5;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well looks like they all use methods 4 and 3

So you only need to define the methods in one class, the other classes can then extend it.

The other methods could be handled by traits but its a bit messy 'cause you'd need to have a trait per method

The same applies to the properties.

```
class class1 { 
  use Method1,Method2;
  public method method3($x) {echo('hey '.$x;}
  public method method4($x) {echo('seeya '.$x;}
}

class class2 extends class1{ 
  use Method2,Method5;
}

class class3 extends class1{ 
  use Method1,Method5;      
}

trait Method1 {
  public method method1($x) {echo('hello '.$x;}
} 

trait Method2 {
  public method method2($x) {echo('goodby '.$x;}
} 

trait Method5 {
  public method method5($x) {echo('latter '.$x;}
}
```

**EDIT**

I just realized that all the classes would end up with a method 1 and 2 as they extend class1 which uses them, so.. I guess you'd be better to have all the methods in separate traits and add them with `use` as required and not bother with `extends`

I still don't much care for it though

Comment: Thanks Andrew,  I somewhat came up with a similar approach (see my proposed answer).  Not sure what I think about it either.

Comment: The code you posted in the edit looks good. As useful as traits are, they don't play too well with netbeans, it does tend to break the intellisense / code usage detection unfortunately. I'd be interested to know how it plays with your IDE and if well, which one you use

Comment: I've never yet used netbeans.  I use NuShere's PHPed.  The code I showed was just made on a text editor, so I am not sure what PHPed will think of it.